# Bluebird promise resolve(data) is undefined in client code

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Hiyas. I have a simple app whereby a client is expecting a promise as a result, but upon calling the resolve() method, the promise keeps returning undefined as the result.

The client code:

```
UsersRepo.findOneAsync({id: id}).then(function(err, result) {
    console.log("UserService promise resolution", err, result);
});
```

This outputs "null" and "undefined", for err and result, respectively

The code that is doing the work and returning the promise:

```
findOneAsync: function(args) {
    var where = ""; //omitted

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.query("Select * from users" + where + " limit 1", function(err, result) {
            var res = { id: 1, username: 'username', firstName: 'First', lastName: 'Last' };

            if(err != null) {
                console.log("REJECT", err);
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("RESOLVE", res);
                resolve(null, res);
            }
        });
    });

    return promise;
}
```

As you can see, I'm just returning some static data for this test (the 'res' variable). In the client code, the console statement always prints out:

```
UserService promise resolution null undefined
```

I don't get this. It looks like I'm doing everything correctly: calling the resolve() method with the data, and the client code is using .then(function(err, result)) properly, so it seems. Why isn't data being received from the client end?

Thanks for any help!

==>

**Solution:**

As mentioned below, Bluebird's reject and resolve only take one argument. The first 'null' was only being seen. Changing the code to 'resolve(res)' worked. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resolve/Reject both accept a single parameter ... hence why your result is undefined, as the second value you pass to resolve is never used, and the first is null

What you want to do instead is

```
UsersRepo.findOneAsync({id: id}).then(function(result) {
    console.log("UserService promise resolution", result);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("UserService promise error", err);
});

findOneAsync: function(args) {
    var where = ""; //omitted

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.query("Select * from users" + where + " limit 1", function(err, result) {
            var res = { id: 1, username: 'username', firstName: 'First', lastName: 'Last' };

            if(err != null) {
                console.log("REJECT", err);
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("RESOLVE", res);
                resolve(res);
            }
        });
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bluebird's `then` does not take in an `err`. Instead, then takes in two functions, the first being for resolve, and the second for being reject. you can also use `catch` for handling errors.

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/then.html

Edit: [@JaromandaX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33966471/2129835) is correct, the resolve function should only take in one parameter.

You should only `resolve(res)`, in addition to not expecting the error object to get passed into the `then` callback.

Comment: Ahhhh, there we go. Sheesh. Thank you!

Comment: `bluebird's then` = that's actaully how **ALL** promises work

Comment: Such a quandary over which answer to accept. You answered first, but Jaromanda more thoroughly, so it seems. Hah, oh man.

Comment: actually I answered first, but first doesn't always mean best :p

Comment: You know, you're right! hah.. I was looking at the numbers "6 minutes ago, 7 minutes ago" and my brain didn't really process it, got it backwards. Ah, all is right on the internet. G'night ;)