# Bluebird's Promise resolve returns undefined

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm new to Promise, so I was trying out Bluebird's Promise APIs. I have the following method that returns a `Promise.try()`

**CheckDb - Promise Method**

```
const Prom = require("bluebird")

..........
..........

let checkDb = () => {
 return Prom.try(() => {
   SomePromiseMethod().then(result => {
    if (//some condition) {
      let resp = { 
          res: result, 
          somethingelse : somethingelse 
      }
      return Prom.resolve(resp)
    }
    else 
      return Prom.reject(new Error("some reason"));
   }, err => {
      return Prom.reject(err);
   })
   .catch(err => {
     return Prom.reject(err);
   });
 });
}
```

**SomeTask - Method calling the promise method**

```
exports.someTask = () => {
      checkDb().then(resolved => {
       console.log(resolved) // coming undefined
      }, 
      rejected => {
       console.error(rejected);
      })
      .catch(err => {console.error(err)});
    }
```

The problem here is that the `resolved` component of the `then` method of the Promise function is returning undefined.

I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361908/bluebird-promises-returns-undefined-when-return-inside-then-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966436/bluebird-promise-resolvedata-is-undefined-in-client-code), but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: `return Prom.try({
   SomePromiseMethod().then` is a syntax error

Comment: replace your first codeblock with [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hg0X9yUb) and it will work (you don't even need to require bluebird!!!)

Comment: note, `.catch(err => {
     return Prom.reject(err);
   });` is just the same as not having the catch at all ... similarly with the onrejected handler above it - there's no reason for it at all

Comment: @bambam Updated

Comment: @JaromandaX It was a mistake while I was copy pasting the code. The code has always been how the example looks now.

Comment: well, then your result should not be undefined - oh, wait ... you've left out a return ... `return SomePromiseMethod()`

Comment: but `, err => {
            return Prom.reject(err);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return Prom.reject(err);
        });` is still redundant code - remove it, it does nothing (it returns a rejected promise from a rejection - redundant)

Comment: `Promise.try` doesn't know what to resolve unless you tell it what to resolve  by returning something ... but since you're already using a function that returns a Promise (`SomePromiseMethod`) and you don't need to deal with the situation in the example for Promise.try in the documentation, Promise.try is **also not required for this code** - your 20+ lines of code can be rewritten as I've already shown in [a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hg0X9yUb) - that code functions identically to yours

Answer (score 1):

Try to return the value directly without using this Prom.resolve, like this:

```
...
        return SomePromiseMethod().then(result => {
            if (//some condition) {
              let resp = { 
                  res: result, 
                  somethingelse : somethingelse 
              }
              return resp
            }
            else 
              throw new Error("some reason"));
           }
    ...
```

If you are in the "then" method of a promise, you resolve it by returning a value, which is passed to the next "then" method in the chain.

You would use the resolve method explicitly if you had:

- a defer created "by hand" and you wanted to resolve it
- a promise created by you if you wanted to "promisify" something that is not a promise, like this example below:

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      ...
      resolve(value);

  })

Which is not your case. 
(Edited this part of the answer to avoid misinterpretation)

Comment: not sure why you brought up promisifying - since the code in the question clearly doesn't need promisifying (it's already over-promisified as it is!!!)

Comment: Thats what I'm saying: there's no need for the Prom.resolve and things like that in his code. I was just trying to give an example on when should he use that (and, sorry if I was not clear: this is my first time trying to contribute here :P)

Comment: No problem. I edited my answer trying to make it clear. After your comment, I've read it again and saw it was not so clear. Thx!